# Поочередная заливка кнопок onClick

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать чтоб при нажатии одной кнопки, загоралась например зеленым, а при нажатии второй - первая окрашивалась в серый, а эта самая вторая кнопка в зеленый. Каким скриптом это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное Вы хотели что-то такое.

```js
firstBtn.onclick = function() { 
   this.style.background = "green";
   secondBtn.style.background = "gray";
}

secondBtn.onclick = function() { 
   firstBtn.style.background = "gray";
   this.style.background = "green";
}
```

```html
<button id="firstBtn">Первая</button>
<button id="secondBtn">Вторая</button>
```

Comment: А если первую нажимаю то вторая не становится серой почему-то

Comment: тупонул я немного , извиняюсь что полностью не уточнил (

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, изменил, можете попробовать.

Comment: спасибо огромное , самое оно )

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, не за что:)

Comment: Я извиняюсь ,а Вы бы не могли глянуть эту тему ? Переключение кнопок

Comment: Я просто немного переделал но вот что-то пошло не так (